# Customised dialog box with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, dialog, xamarin.forms, customization

I need to be able to make this kind of dialog box to be displayed when a button is pressed. I am using Acr.UserDialogs for simple dialog boxes but I don't think there is any way to get such a dialog using this library.

Any ideas on how I can do this in Xamarin Forms?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) plugin to display a page modally

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own layout and use this awesome plugin to display your layout as popup

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

**How To Use**  --snippet from the link

Open new PopupPage

```
Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.PushPopupAsync
```

*Hide last PopupPage*

```
Task PopAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopPopupAsync
```